# Quick way of creating a long data frame for repeated values and variable characters

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

Is there a quick way of creating a data frame for this (4columns x 3060 rows)?

```
Column 1: Repeating (1:17) until row 3060
Column 2: Repeating: (6x"W", 5x"M", 6x"E")like this: (W, W, W, W, W, W, M, M, M, M, M, E, E, E, E, E, E) until row 3060
Column 3: (A1x17rows, A2x17 rows....) for this this:  A1:A27, B1:B92, C1:C61) 
Column 4: Values ( I can copy form an excel sheet) ie: 0.06,0.03...
```

So the head would look like this

```
> head(df)
  Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
1       1       W      A1  0.0060
2       2       W      A2  0.0030
3       3       W      A3  0.0120
4       4       W      A4  0.0238
5       5       W      A5  0.0020
6       6       W      A6  0.0040
```

I have many errors but started with this

```
Column1 = c(1:17)
Column2 =c(6x"W", 5x"M",6x"E")
Column3 = c("A1":"A27"...)
Column4 = c("Values")

df <- data.frame(Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4)
```

Comment: i think the e xpanded valuess would be more than 2060

Comment: @akrun 3060 it is sorry ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sample answer:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble::tibble(
  ID = 1:3060, #use this to sort
  column1 = rep(1:17,180),
  column2 = rep(c(rep("W",6),rep("M",5),rep("E",6) ), 180),
  column3 = rep(c(paste0("A",rep(1:27)), paste0("B",rep(1:92)), paste0("C",rep(1:61))),17)
)
```

To add in your excel you can try something like this. Copy the excel column without the header.

```
column4 <- read_table(clipboard())
df %>%  bind_cols(column4)
```

Comment: is there a way to add column so I have A1x17, A2x17... A27x17 other than this..
Column5 = rep(c(rep("A1",17),rep("A2",17).....rep("A27",17))))

Comment: the column could actually just be with numbers 1x17, 2x17.... until 27x17

Comment: related to this, on another df but related: If n=92 (where Z1x17, ..Z92x17, Is there a quicker way of creating a column other than 

    Column = rep(c(rep("Z1",17),rep("Z2",17),rep("Z3",17),rep("Z4",17),..., rep("Z92",17)

?

Comment: something like this: `rep(paste0("Z", 1:6),17) %>% str_sort() %>% head(92)`

Answer (score 2):

We can use `crossing`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)  
crossing(col1 = 1:17, col3 = c(paste0("A", 1:27), paste0("B", 1:92), paste0("C", 1:61))) %>% 
      mutate(col2 = rep(c("W", "M", "E"), length.out = 3060))
```